# UIWebview drop is not working in ios11

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, ios11

I have `UIWebview` in editing mode. By default `UIWebView` supports drag and drop. But in my app, when I drag a text content and drop in webview it's not accepting it. Any possible solutions?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you show screen shot

Comment: @Lalitkumar attached the screenshot